# Алгоритм расстановки логических элементов в узлы дерева

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, бинарное-дерево

Такой вопрос, как представлять в виде дерева логические выражения. Пример:

**(n (A o B)) a ((C a D) o (n E))**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По какому принципу выполняется расстановка логических операций? Почему корнем является and, а не or

Comment: в порядке приоритетов операций, в какой еще принцип может быть? скобки главные, поэтому тут и `and` в центре

Comment: Так ведь какая операция будет самой **последней** при вычислении? Вот она и находится в корне...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Выражение** состоит из констант , переменных , указателей функций,
>   знаков операций и скобок. Выражение задает правило вычисления
>   некоторого значения. Порядок вычисления определяется старшинством
>   (приоритетом) содержащихся в нем операций. В языке pascal принят
>   следующий приоритет операций:
>
> 1. унарная операция `not`, унарный минус `-`, унарный плюс `+`, взятие адреса `@`, возведение в степень `**`
> 2. операции умножения: `*`, `/`, `div`, `mod`, `and`, `shl`, `shr`
> 3. операции сложения: `+`, `-`, `or`, `xor`
> 4. операции отношения: `=`, `<`, `>`,`<>`, `<=`, `>=`, `in`
>
> Выражение просматривается слева направо, сравниваются две
>   последовательные операции, и выполняется та из них, чей приоритет
>   выше. Порядок выполнения операций можно изменить с помощью круглых
>   скобок. **Часть выражения, заключенная в круглые скобки, вычисляется в
>   первую очередь**

первый [источник](http://de.ifmo.ru/bk_netra/page.php?dir=3&tutindex=15&index=15&layer=1) из гугла, чутка подправленный.

в вашем случае есть пара равнозначных скобок, объединенных через `and`, так что он и получается в центре.

Answer (score 1):

В порядке вычисления, грубо говоря.

```
(n (A o B)) a ((C a D) o (n E))
```

Это никак не

```
X o Y
```

правда? Это

```
X a Y
```

так что рисуем `a` в корне, а `X` и `Y` - листочки. Но что такое `X`? Это

```
(n (A o B))
```

Так что вместо листочка рисуем узел `n` и к нему очередной листик - который на самом деле не листик, а `A o B`.

И точно так же с правой стороны.

Вычисления же ведем наоборот, от листьев к корню.

Ну, а сам алгоритм - это уже синтаксический анализ, его в одном ответе не уложишь. Возьмите "Компиляторы" Ахо, Ульмана с соавторами, там отлично изложено...